# how to make httpd work with two different versions of openssl

Tags: linux, lamp, apache

My OS is CentOS 6.2.
I need to use php 5.2.4, which depends on openssl 0.9.8e. But openssl 1.0.x was shipped with OS.
So I built openssl 0.9.8e.
Now there are openssl 0.9.8e and php 5.2.4 on my OS.
/opt/php5.2.4/
/opt/openssl0.9.8e/

php cli run properly, but when I used php with apache. Httpd fails to start.
Httpd was installed from CentOS repository.

The problem seems to be --
Httpd used libmysql.so, which depends on openssl 1.0.x.
Httpd also used libphp5.so, which depends on openssl 0.9.8e.

How can I make them work together?

Answer (score 0):

1. Live with the fact that you cannot reliably mix libraries of different versions in a single process when their symbol tables contribute to the global namespace (i.e. the standard DT_NEEDED mechanism or by using dlopen with RTLD_GLOBAL). That means you either have to get your httpd parts (including sql) to use openssl 0.8, or make php use 1.0. The latter should not be particular hard given that openssl changed little ever since.
2. Or, you could run PHP in FastCGI mode. This also allows to use e.g. apache2-event instead of ye olde prefork-er. There are a handful of ways to pull this off (choice of daemons and apache modules)— one that comes out of the box is php-fpm-5.3.3+ in conjunction with apache-2.4+'s mod_proxy_fcgi.